# NullPointer Exception onClick

Tags: android, android-activity

My code is:

```
public class Register extends Activity {

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";

    // Defining layout items
    EditText inputFirstName;
    EditText inputLastName;
    EditText inputUsername;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    Button btnRegister;
    TextView registerErrorMsg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        // Defining all layout items
        inputFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
        inputLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        registerErrorMsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.register_error);

        // Button which Switches back to the login screen on clicked
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bktologin);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                finish();
            }
        });

        // Register Button click event. A toast is set to alert when the fields are empty
        // Another toast is set to alert Username must be 5 characters.
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                if ((!inputUsername.getText().toString().equals("")) && (!inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) && (!inputFirstName.getText().toString().equals("")) && (!inputLastName.getText().toString().equals("")) && (!inputEmail.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                    Log.e(KEY_ERROR, "Pride do kle4");
                    if (inputUsername.getText().toString().length() > 4) {
                        Log.e(KEY_ERROR, "Pride do kle2");
                        NetAsync (v);
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.e(KEY_ERROR, "Pride do kle3");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Username should be minimum 5 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(KEY_ERROR, "Pride do kle5");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "One or more fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Async Task to check whether internet connection is working
    private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            nDialog.setMessage("Loadig...");
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th) {
            if (th == true) {
                nDialog.dismiss();
                new ProcessRegister().execute();
            } else {
                nDialog.dismiss();
                registerErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
            }
        }
    }
```

and I get this error :

```
08-30 17:11:41.155  26407-26407/com.knedl.testloginapp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418adda0)
08-30 17:11:41.155  26407-26407/com.knedl.testloginapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.knedl.testloginapp, PID: 26407
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.knedl.testloginapp.Register$2.onClick(Register.java:85)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4640)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19425)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I would change `if ((!inputUsername.getText().toString().equals("")) &&...` and so on to:  `if (inputUsername.length()<1 && ...`

Answer (score 2):

Your `inputEmail` does not seem to be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

you forget to initialize the inputEmail in the following code

```
 // Defining all layout items
        inputFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
        inputLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email); // this is the line you are forgetting
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
```

Comment: I agree, just found it as well but you were quicker. To the author, the error occurs because on your onClick you are checking if all the fields have value in them while inputEmail is declared but not initialized.

Comment: thanks , how stupid off me :)

Comment: @Dawid Czerwinski yes your are right.